# jQuery - Calling .trigger('click') vs .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery what is the better way to trigger an event such as click? Using the `.trigger('click')` function or calling `.click()`?

I have always triggered this event by using `.click()` but suddenly decided maybe I should be using `.trigger('click')` instead.

I use these event triggers to trigger event listeners created with `.on('click', function(){...})`.

I have checked the [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), searched other stackoverflow posts [[ 1 ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519159/jquery-trigger-a-click-vs-function-call) [[ 2 ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486630/jquery-trigger-click-vs-click) and I can see no reason to use one over the other.

I would be more inclined to use `.trigger()` to keep all event triggering consistent, as this can be used to call any event including custom events. But it would seem `.trigger()` does not work in all cases.

What is the best way to trigger an event? `.trigger('click')` or `.click()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using `.trigger()` you have the advantage of being able to pass additional parameters, whereas `.click()` must be called without any.

Taken from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('#foo').bind('custom', function(event, param1, param2) {
  alert(param1 + "\n" + param2);
});
$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']);
```

*`'Custom'` and `'Event'` are being passed to the event handler as `param1` and `param2` respectively*

Besides that, the `.click()` is unlike other functions that implement get / set based on the number of arguments, because it implements trigger / set instead. Using a dedicated `.trigger()`, to me, is more logical.

Comment: Regarding your last point about `.click()` both registering and triggering click handlers (depending on arguments), I don't disagree, but then the same thing applies to lots of jQuery methods (`.html()`, `.css()`, etc.), so you get used to it pretty fast once you get into jQuery.

Comment: @nnnnnn But using that logic, `.click()` should give me the list of event handlers :)

Comment: Well if you're going to bring logic into it... (All I'm saying is that, right or wrong, having a method do seemingly opposite things depending on the argument(s) is the jQuery way.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I've revised my answer though, it's not fair to bring up SRP for a library that aims to be compact; and maybe I've forgotten the other oddities I've come across over the years, but this one just seems to stick out :)

Comment: Ha, well, you could look at `.click()` as being singularly responsible for all things click-related - except that of course it's not because you've got `.trigger()`, `.on()`, etc. +1, by the way.

Comment: sooooo which one is better to use?

Comment: @Vic My opinion on that matter is clearly indicated in the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 8):

One caveat to be aware of when using the jQuery method is that, in addition to being a jQuery method, `.click()` is also a DOM Level 2 [native JavaScript method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) that can be called on HTML elements, such as `<button>` elements.

One place where this can become confusing is if you have a selector like this:

```
$("#element")[0].click();
```

There, you are actually calling the method on the DOM element. For instance, if you tried

```
$("#element")[0].trigger('click');
```

you would get an error that the element has no `trigger` method defined.

Be aware that `$('#element')[0].click();` won't work in Safari, on certain elements. You will need to use a workaround.