# Does the jQuery .click method trigger the .click event handler?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Does the jQuery `.click` method trigger the `.click` event handler?

And if not is there a way to trigger the event handler (basically, on my page, links can be clicked on by the mouse or triggered by my JavaScript and I want to handle what happens for both these cases in the same way - i.e. handle all within the click event handler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try: [.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). Like this:

```
$('#element').trigger("click");
```

You could also pass additional parameters to it:

```
$('#element').trigger("click",parameter);
```

Your event handler looks like this:

```
$('#element').on('click', function(event, parameter) {

});
```

Some opinions think that `trigger("click")` is better than `.click`. Check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click) and [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505003/jquery-calling-triggerclick-vs-click) for the differences between `.click` and `.trigger("click")`

Answer (score 1):

yes [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) can trigger `click` event

you can do it like this

```
$('element').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) says that calling it without arguments is a shortcut for `.trigger( "click" )`.

The documentation for [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) says:

> **Description**: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

Taken together, this clearly says that calling `.click()` will trigger the click handlers.