# Chain a div click to another with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if I'm using the correct lingo,

But I want to click a div and when I do it should cause another to be clicked after.

Ex click div 1 then div 2 gets clicked (but not by user, just by JS)

Is this possible?

There is already a huge function attached to div 2 when clicked, so I need to to link the two if that makes sense. Easier hopefully than sorting through lots of code and trying to add it in.

Any help?

Comment: Yeah... Show us your JS code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use:

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
  $('#div2').trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: also, see this for advantage of using trigger vs .click()  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505003/jquery-calling-triggerclick-vs-click

Answer (score 2):

You can just call `click()` on div 2:

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
   //your code
   $('#div2').click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#div1").click(function() {
    // Do stuff...
    // Then click the other DIV
    $("#div2").click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, in the click handler for div one call

```
$("#div2").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div1').click(function() {
    $('#div2').click();
});
```

Edit:

This solves your problem because it attaches a listener to `div1` and executes a function whenever `div1` is clicked. It just so happens that you want to emit another event for `div1`, which, in jQuery shorthand, is written with the `.click()` function.

Giving `.click()` a function as a parameter sets the callback for the click event, which can manually be called by calling the function without any parameters.

Comment: Consider editing your answer to make it more descriptive, e.g. why does this solve the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible creating the function for the click on the  1.

With

```
$('#iddiv1').click(function(){
   //your code
   $('#iddiv2').click();
});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by doing so:

```
$("#idDiv1").click(function(){
    //do what you want
    $("#idDiv2").trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an onclick event TRIGGER a click on another div.

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    $('#bar').trigger("click");
});

$('#bar').click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```